# Jquery draggable and droppable, switch to originalPosition another draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm working with Jquery UI draggable and droppable.
I have a container that accepts all the divs of the .category1 class, and what I have to do is:
If I put a div into the container that already has another div, revert the old div back to the 
original position.
This is the code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $("#Part1").draggable({ revert: "invalid", snap: "#Part1Container", snapMode: "inner" 
});


$("#Part1Container").droppable({
        accept: ".category1",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            //Some other logic
            }
        }
    });
```

And the Html

```
<div id="Part1" class="ui-widget-content category1"></div>
<div id="Part2" class="ui-widget-content category1"></div>
```

I want the Part1 to be back to the original position if I insert Part2 in the container, and viceversa. And this has to work for n divs of the same class.

Any suggestions?

Tnx in advance :)

Comment: why don't you look into clone, or use a handler, or look at the draggable options, im sure there is something there to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by assigning it a class when it goes into the container the first time, and then delete it when moving another div

```
            $(".inCategory2").animate({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).removeClass("inCategory2");
            ui.draggable.addClass("inCategory2");
```